# Is there any way to download a pdf into the mobile without using cordova plugins?

Tags: file, cordova, extjs

I am using sencha touch to build hybrid apps. I need to download a file into the local storage of the mobile. Is this possible without using cordova/phonegap plugins.

Comment: no, you have to use file transfer plugin to download

Comment: ok will it work fine across all platforms

Comment: If you require it to work across all platforms, add it to your question please.

Comment: `@PeterIvan Plese suggest now.